# Pypy Pandas not installing

Tags: python, pandas, pip, pypy

I'm new to Pypy, I've been working with python for accouple of years and I decided to give pypy a try! But I'm having a problem installing the pandas library. I can't post the full lenght of the error because StackOverflow won't let me... but this is a suppress version that did....

I ran:

```
pypy3 -m pip install pandas
```

And the outcome was:

```
Using cached pandas-1.2.4.tar.gz (5.5 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\pypy3.7\pypy3.exe' 'C:\Program Files (x86)\pypy3.7\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\GONALO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f_kp3snm\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.29.21,<3' 'numpy==1.16.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy; python_version>='"'"'3.9'"'"''
     cwd: None
Complete output (269 lines):
Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.9"' don't match your environment
Collecting setuptools
  Using cached setuptools-56.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (784 kB)
Collecting wheel
  Using cached wheel-0.36.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
Collecting Cython<3,>=0.29.21
  Using cached Cython-0.29.23-py2.py3-none-any.whl (978 kB)
Collecting numpy==1.16.5
  Using cached numpy-1.16.5.zip (5.1 MB)
Using legacy setup.py install for numpy, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, Cython, numpy
    Running setup.py install for numpy: started
    Running setup.py install for numpy: finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\pypy3.7\pypy3.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\GONALO~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f70s2rin\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\GONALO~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f70s2rin\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\GONALO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-bkj0w_a2\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\GONALO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f_kp3snm\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\GONALO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f_kp3snm\overlay\include\numpy'
         cwd: C:\Users\GONALO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f70s2rin\numpy\
     UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    blas_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries blas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\pypy3.7\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE
(..............................)

    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\pypy3.7\pypy3.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\GONALO~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f70s2rin\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\GONALO~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f70s2rin\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\GONALO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-bkj0w_a2\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\GONALO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f_kp3snm\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\GONALO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f_kp3snm\overlay\include\numpy' Check the logs for full command output.
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\pypy3.7\pypy3.exe' 'C:\Program Files (x86)\pypy3.7\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\GONALO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f_kp3snm\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.29.21,<3' 'numpy==1.16.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy; python_version>='"'"'3.9'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Can anyone help? I have no idea what i'm doing wrong....Thank you all very much for the attention and help!

Comment: you can give it a try through wheel. i.e first install wheel `pip install wheel` and then run your command to install pandas.

Comment: @simpleApp That didn't work for me, With pypy3 V7.3.7 (python 3.8.12)

Answer (score 0):

Please use the conda distribution of pypy, since most of the packages will be provided without compilation. [Source](https://conda-forge.org/blog/posts/2020-03-10-pypy/)

Comment: Even with conda pypy3, pandas isn't installable. pypy3 V7.3.7 (python 3.8.12)

Comment: conda has not yet released packages for pypy3.8. pypy3.7 should work.

Comment: Tried with 3.7, it hasn't worked, and I could get pypy3.8 with default methods, can you point to any source when you say it's not released? I could get it with `conda create -n my_env  -c conda-forge pypy3.8` . Also have you tried with 3.7? That would work for me for the time being, but is doesn't install pandas!

Comment: conda install -c conda-forge pandas

Comment: Sorry, hit "return" too soon. Setting up a conda pypy3.7 environment on windows and doing "conda install -c conda-forge pandas" gets me pandas-1.3.4. Does it fail for you? How?

Comment: As for 3.8 releasing packages, see this issue https://github.com/conda-forge/conda-forge-pinning-feedstock/issues/2089