# Why Pandas is not working with PyPy3 and post some errors

Tags: python, pandas, pypy

I am trying to run my Python code by using PyPy3 in order to speed the running time up.
However, I always get this error:

`line 6, in <module> import pandas as pd ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'`

I have done all the steps and tricks that have been posts for years but nothing works.

- [Any way to install Pandas with PyPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39500612/any-way-to-install-pandas-with-pypy)
- [how to install pandas in pypy3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69897855/how-to-install-pandas-in-pypy3)
- [Pypy Pandas not installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67337032/pypy-pandas-not-installing)

I installed pandas package by using `pypy3 -m pip install pandas`. However, I got the following errors:

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
Failed to build numpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
  
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
```

I have already installed Wheel and Numpy.

How can I install pandas in PyPy3, please?

FYI: I am using
macOS 12.6.3 - Python 3.10 and 3.7 - PyPy3 3.10

Comment: There will have been an actual failure logged before you get to the message announcing that it happened. We need to know _how_ it failed, not just _that_ it failed.

Comment: (also, "all the tricks that have been posted for years" tells us nothing; we need to know **exactly** what you tried, and **exactly** how each attempt failed).